# Problems admin'ing my cluster on windows

Tags: redhat-datagrid

I’m having problems admin’ing my cluster. I can run ‘standalone -c clustered.xml’ on Windows and everything looks ok. However, if I run ‘domain.bat’ I can’t see how to configure the domain.xml file so that it can see anything else on my local server. Is this somehow related to the host.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

The domain mode is for administration, you can configure servers in cluster mode.
If you start with domain.[bat||sh] there are at least two java processes running.
A HostController, for administration/configuration and a ProcessController to start/stop or restart configured processes.

The domain.xml contains the configuration and here the profile is stored, i.e. caches, endpoints, ports, security etc.
The host.xml contains the server for this host-machine and the link to the domain-master.

Configuration is possible via console GUI or CLI commandline.